# Prove existence of a point in certain conditions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $ f:[0,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a function and $ F $ an antiderivative of $ f $ with $ F(2)=0 $. Prove that there exists $ a \in (0,2) $ so that $ (1-2a)F(a)+af(a)=0 $   $ (*) $.

If we put $ a:=0 $ in $ (*) $ we obtain that $ F(0)=0=F(2) $, so using Rolle's theorem we have that there exists $ a \in (0,2) $ with $ f(a)=0 $. Also, for $ a:=\frac{1}{2} $ we have $ f(\frac{1}{2})=0 $.

Comment: Are $f$ and $F$ continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x) = xe^{-2x}F(x)$. Notice that $g(0) = g(2) = 0$, and since $g$ is differentiable, by Rolle's Theorem there exists $a\in(0,2)$ such that $g'(a) = 0$. Since
\begin{align} g'(x) &= e^{-2x}F(x) + x(e^{-2x}F(x))' \\
&= e^{-2x}F(x) + x(-2e^{-2x}F(x) + e^{-2x}f(x)) \\
&= e^{-2x}((1-2x)F(x)+xf(x))
\end{align}
it follows that
$$e^{-2a}((1-2a)F(a)+af(a)) = g'(a) = 0\implies (1-2a)F(a)+af(a) = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: Nice solution! +1.